# Fuse file system with “default permission” option

Tags: filesystems, mount, linux-kernel, ext4, fuse

I am new to fuse. I have mounted fuse by the following command.

```
/home/bin/fusexmp /mnt/fuse -o default_permissions -o allow_other -o nonempty -o hard_remove -d
```

Now If I login as "test" user and tried to create a file called "testfile".

```
test@11540302:/registration> touch testfile
touch: setting times of `testfile': Permission denied
```

Strace output:

```
uname({sys="Linux", node="11540302", ...}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x8055000
brk(0x8076000)                          = 0x8076000
open("testfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) =    3
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
utimensat(0, NULL, NULL, 0)             = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
close(0)                                = 0
```

But "testfile" creation is successful with owner as **root** user,

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root trusted     0 Jan 19 13:51 testfile
```

I can understand that fuse application is running in root level, file creation happened with the owner as root. Because of that test user cannot perform any operation on "testfile".

**My question:**

**1. Since I have given "allow_other" while mounting, why test user cannot having privileges to access the "testfile"?**

**2. After logging as "test" user and trying to create "testfile", why it is assigning "root" as owner of the file instead of "test". This is observed even after giving "default_permission" during mount.**

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: FUSE stands for "file system in user space", so it's the collective name for file systems that are represented by user space programs. There's quite a few of them, so you can't "mount fuse", you always need to use a specific filesystem (which happens to be implemented via fuse). `/mnt/fuse` isn't a command. `/mnt` and its subdirectories are the usual places to mount filesystems. So I'm not sure *what* you mounted (if anything), and I don't understand what you want to achieve in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have mounted fuse with root user. If i login with different user and create a file, it is getting created with owner as root user. With is point please check my questions. Hope i am clear with my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me clarify: You didn't "mount fuse", you used the example program `fusexmp`, which is a very simple fuse program that just passes on all operations to the standard Linux library calls. This is just an example program, and a very boring one.

You didn't say as which user you did this mount operation, but I assume you did this as `root` (because otherwise `allow_other` wouldn't have worked, and it wouldn't have created `testfile` with owner `root`). Note that you can in principle mount FUSE filesystems as any user.

So when the `test` user executed `touch`, first he opened the file on the fuse-mounted filesystem. Because you used `default_permissions`, the system checked if user `test` is allowed to create files in this particular directory (which apparently succeeded), and then let `fusexmp` create the file. As `fusexmp` runs as `root`, this file was created as `root`.

Next, `touch` wanted to set the date. Because you have used `default_permissions`, the system checked if user `test` is allowed to set the date on this particular file. That is not the case, so the system aborted with a permission error, no matter if the program `fusexmp` would actually be able to set the date (which it would, running as root).

I'm still not sure of the point of this exercise: You used an example program in an unusual way, and then wondered about the results. If you give `default_permissions`, then you should also make sure that your userspace program creates files with the correct owner etc. (which `fusexmp` doesn't).

If you want to understand fuse filesystems from the point of the user, I suggest you experiment with real examples, like [sshfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS). Or write your own fuse program and handle permissions etc. yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this problem.

[Detailed explanation for this issue.](https://lwn.net/Articles/131856/)

Solution:

As @dirkt said we need to handle permissions on our own.

**Code to get the caller uid and gid:**

> fuse_get_context()->uid;
>
> fuse_get_context()->gid;

Get the caller user id and group id and set the ownership of the file/directory while creating via fuse API's.

Always there is room for improvement. Kindly correct me if I am not correct.

Thank you dirkt for your explanation.

Comment: The thing is that it may or may not be necessary to handle permissions *at all*. It totally depends on what are you trying to represent as a FUSE file system, and for what purpose. If I have, say, a diskimage for some retro computer, just let the user mount it as a FUSE file system, and as the diskimage doesn't have anything equivalent to Linux uid's and gid's, substitute to uid and gid of the user who mounted it. It certainly makes no sense to add permission handling to the demo `fusexmp`.